# How can you tell what namespace constants have been put in in swift?

Tags: cocoa, swift

In swift, a lot of cocoa and framework constants have been put into namespaces.  For example, `NSCompositeSourceOver` is now `NSCompositingOperation.CompositeSourceOver`.

This is generally a good thing.  However, sometimes it's hard to work out where Apple have put certain constants.  For example, I currently need `kCGDesktopWindowLevel`, and I can't find the damn thing.  (There is `kCGDesktopWindowLevelKey`, but that's not the same thing.)

Is there a reference for this, or some set of files I can grep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the original `CGWindowLevel.h`, `kCGDesktopWindowLevel` is a macro defined to `CGWindowLevelForKey(kCGDesktopWindowLevelKey)`. The macro was not imported, but the latter works fine in Swift as long as you add some type conversions: `Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(CGWindowLevelKey(kCGDesktopWindowLevelKey)))`. (You might wish to [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) since these type conversions are required.) You can see some of these things by ⌘-clicking on the `CGWindowLevelForKey` function, or using `:print_module CoreGraphics` from `swift -integrated-repl`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  Annoyingly, though, the compiler actually requires `self.window.level = Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(CGWindowLevelKey(kCGDesktopWindowLevelKey)))` in order to sort out the type conversions ><